# UniData Data Access Products for .NET

Tags: .net, database, unidata, uniobjects

I am doing some research about how to access data in a UniData database from .NET code.

From what I have found, I can use [UniObjects for .NET](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/u2/middleware/index.html#uniobjects-n) and [U2.NET](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/u2/u2-net/). I have also found [this information](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0903linqentity/index.html?S_TACT=105AGX11&S_CMP=LP), which I think is possible by using U2.NET, but I'm not quite sure.

I am also unsure as to the cost of these products, and if they are free, how to download them.

Can anyone answer these questions and advise what the differences are between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UniObjects for .NET is free, and part of the [UniData](http://www.intl-spectrum.com/database/8/UniData.aspx) Client CD.  U2.NET is a paid for product that is actually BluFinity's MV.NET repackaged and sold under the IBM name.

U2.NET has a lot more features than UniObjects for .NET.  UniObjects for .NET is basically the core UniData API recast into .NET... File (Table) opens, Dynamic Arrays, Read/write/delete records, OCONV/ICONV, subroutine calls, EXECUTE, etc

U2.NET take the core that UniObjects supplies and extends it to easily make DataSets and Class, SISS, and other .NET feature easier to access

Comment: Where can the UniObjects for .NET be downloaded from. I don't have the cd.

Comment: I'm also looking. I posted the [following][1] as I thought they would get it working however installer says it could not find the provider.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126574/where-to-get-uniobjects-for-net

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [jBase mv.NET](http://www.jbase.com/products/mvnet.html). We evaluated it for accessing IBM UniVerse databases from .NET with ADO.NET a while back. It did well in our tests but the project was canceled so we never got to use it.

Comment: I believe it's designed to work with all of the multi-valued databases, including UniData. Not 100% sure on that. Check their website. There should be a free trial period for testing it out.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126574/where-to-get-uniobjects-for-net) question:

If  you have Unidata, you should have a copy of the CDs, or at least the setup package for the Client Tools.  You may need to talk to your system admins to find it, though.